# How to find whether a number belongs to a particular range in Python?

Tags: python, range

Suppose I want to check if `x` belongs to range 0 to 0.5. How can I do it?

Can I use the `range` function for that?

Answer (score 80):

No, you can't do that. `range()` expects integer arguments. If you want to know if `x` is inside this range try some form of this:

```
print 0.0 <= x <= 0.5
```

Be careful with your upper limit. If you use `range()` it is excluded (`range(0, 5)` does not include 5!)

Comment: -1: No reference to the documentation and no example of what range really does.  +1: Being polite in the face of an absurd question.

Comment: "Range" is also an english word, not only a function name ;)

Answer (score 26):

```
print 'yes' if 0 < x < 0.5 else 'no'
```

[`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) is for generating arrays of consecutive integers

Comment: thank you..i got range() concept
is there any built-in method ?

Comment: built-in method for writing 0 < x < 0.5?

Comment: how's writing 0<x<0.5 not built-in? why do you need method?

Comment: i want to know if there is any method

Comment: Using built-in methods: (0.0).__lt__(x).__and__((5.0).__gt__(x))

Comment: @vartec: Add `print` before 'yes' to match the question exactly.

Comment: @Sebastian: done, however, I'm not sure anymore what the question is exactly ;-)

Answer (score 9):

To check whether some number n is in the inclusive range denoted by the two number a and b you do either

```
if   a <= n <= b:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

use the replace `>=` and `<=` with `>` and `<` to check whether `n` is in the exclusive range denoted by `a` and `b` (i.e. `a` and `b` are not themselves members of the range).

Range will produce an arithmetic progression defined by the two (or three) arguments converted to integers. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?#range). This is not what you want I guess.

Comment: your alternative version is just outright wrong

Comment: wrong as in concept-wrong, not typo-wrong

Comment: Well, it works for integers. For floats it *can* work, depending on values of b and n.

Comment: It doesn't work for integers. Consider a = b = n = 1.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> s = 1.1
>>> 0<= s <=0.2
False
>>> 0<= s <=1.2
True
```

Answer (score 7):

```python
if num in range(min, max):
  """do stuff..."""
else:
  """do other stuff..."""
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP's example of `float`s. See @vartec's answer.

Comment: Likely, this is a very slow implementation.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's implemented efficiently in CPython as `min <= num < max` (with special checks for `stride != 1`). You can check out the implementation in `range_contains` and `range_contains_long` in `cpython/Objects/rangeobject.c`

Answer (score 6):

I would use the numpy library, which would allow you to do this for a list of numbers as well:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,])
a[a < 2]
```

Comment: for within a range (0.0 to 5.0) do: a[numpy.logical_and(0.0<a, a<5.0)]

Comment: This is slower and more complex than the highest-rated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Old faithful:

```
if n >= a and n <= b:
```

And it doesn't look like Perl (joke)

Comment: This is not Pythonic.