# learning python the hard way, exercise 35: placing a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

In the mentioned exercise there's this code:

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much=int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit (0)
    else:
        dead ("You greedy bastard!")
```

In the 7th line, I want to put the regular expression [0-9] instead of 0 or 1, so that any inserted number would be passed to the next if statement, so I replaced it with:

```
    if next == [0-9]:
```

but after inserting any number I get the error message:

```
Man, learn to type a number.
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Thank you for help

Comment: `[0-9]` is not a regular expression, its a list with one element, the result of 0-9, which results in `[-9]`.

Comment: Simlar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618093/how-to-find-whether-a-number-belongs-to-a-particular-range-in-python

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Does it mean if I put -9 as an input, it will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work because `-9 in [-9]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5300506/1025391

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I tried using -9 as input, but got the same error.

Comment: Yes because you are checking `'-9' in [-9]` which will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try:
    how_much = int(next)
except ValueError:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

Which will convert your input to an integer unless `next` is something that cannot be converted to an integer. [Read this to learn more about errors and exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

If you insist on using a regular expression, which you absolutely shouldn't:

```
if re.match("\d+", next):
    how_much = int(next)
```

Please don't use the regex.

Comment: `0 <= int(next) <= 9`

Comment: Note that `range(0,10)` will construct a new list for every comparison, and using the `in` operator on that, has an average time complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, however for such a simple program it's not very relevant. Anyway I feel it's more pythonic to follow the EAFP here.

Comment: I mean you shouldn't teach novices bad idioms, even though it's not relevant in a toy example.

Comment: @msvalkon pretty helpful, thanks. Couldn't I just go on with if instatement instead of try?

Comment: @Amateur it's not a very good idea. The `try-except` is a common idiom in python and it's considered pythonic. It will also make sure that you can enter numbers like `500`. It does not limit you either, because you can still have the `if`'s afterwards. @moooeeeep has a very good point about the time complexity of the `in` operator (goes through all items in a sequence) and that the `range` function would generate a new list for each function call.

Comment: @msvalkon message received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are particular about using regular expressions use this

```
import re
try:
  re.match(r"[0-9]", next).group()
  how_much = (int)next
except:
  dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

Comment: There are several problems with your code. One is that if you're going to handle the exception you might as well just do the conversion `how_much = (int)next` and catch any exception that throws. Another problem is that you should never, ever have a bare `except:`, you should only catch the expected exceptions that you know you can handle (sometimes that might be to catch `Exception` but usually only once per program). Finally, if you're going to use a regular expression then it would be clearer just to test the result rather than trying to force an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @scarecrow It's a little difficult for me to understand it right now, but I think  will be helpful in a not far future. Thanks